# Difference In declaring Javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I have been reading a few different Javascript authors and each has their preferred way to declare properties on objects. None of the authors really explains the difference between these different ways. What are the differences and which way is the preferred declaration to us?

```
var One = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.foo = function() {};
    return self;
}

var two = function() {
    foo: function() {}
};

var three = function() {
    var _foo = function() {};

    three.foo = _foo;
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to declare class/object in javascript. Get this link to have 3 of them http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Comment: Your second example is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @pointy what is incorrect about it, and can you fix it?

Comment: `var two = { foo: function(){}, bar: function(){} };` is what you want on the second (my guess).

Comment: Do you have a link or code sample that uses the 3rd pattern?

Comment: See http://www.j-io.org/Javascript-Naming_Conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***tl;dr - See conclusion***

### Introduction

Declaring objects in javascript can be done many different ways, and from my point of view it all depends on how complex your project is.

The examples you proposed would be ways to declare variables within a complex project. You could even say for project maintainability and code quality the examples you proposed can be very interesting.

### Part 1 - First example

Your first example you proposed was this function.

```
var One = function(){
   var self = this;
   self.foo = function(){};
   return self;
}
```

#### Context: Global -> One()

Suppose we don't create an instance of `One` (not using `new`) This function has two objectives.

1. Attach the `foo function` to its parents context (usually window object = globally)
2. Return `foo function`

You could say you're killing *two birds with one stone*. While doing two things at once can be interesting, in the end it could really become a `context` problem.

`Context` is pretty much asking yourself, what does `this` refer to? Non instantiated functions inherit the parents `context` which is fine if none of those parents are instantiated themselves. If this is the case (meaning `this` != window object) and your primary goal was to attach `foo` globally well it just won't work.

#### Context: Self -> new One()

If you call this function with `new`, `this` will be different. `this` will refer to an instance of `One`. This is a lot more logical way.

In the end you could say that an instance of One will feel `almost` like an object.

#### Comparing with objects

I say *almost* mainly because what is the difference if One was:

```
var One_object = {
  foo: function(){}
}
```

Well there isn't really, except you'll be more flexible with an object rather than an `instance` of a function.

```
//This will not work.
var a = new One();
a.titi = function(){
   alert('titi');
}

//This will work
One_object.titi = function(){
   alert('titi');
}
```

#### Improving the example

The only way that `One` as an instance can become interesting is if you declare multiple instances. Performance wise and memory wise it'll be more interesting.

```
var One = function(foo){
   //auto instantiate it's self
   if(!(this instanceof One)){
      return new One(foo);
   }
   this.foo = foo || function(){};
}
```

Creating multiple instances of One with the same function probably defeats the purpose, so here is an example of how you could improve `One`.

```
var a = One(function(){
    alert('instance one');
});

var b = One(function(){
    alert('instance two');
});
```

---

### Part 2 - Second example

```
var two = function() {
    foo: function() {}l
};
```

Is actually wrong as I'm sure you've noticed from the comments. It should be instead:

```
var two = {
        foo: function() {}
    };
```

Where `two` is in fact an `object` and not a `function`.

This way of declaring variables/functions ensures that you are not overriding on a global scope any other function named `"foo"`.

This can be very useful when you have a lot of js and you are declaring a lot of variables.

In this case, to access `foo` you need to simply call `two.foo();`

This is honestly my preferred way of declaring variables.

1. Variables are not scattered all across the js file.
2. They do not override any existing variables with the same name
3. It's clean and maintainable.
4. They can easily be moved around.

With this in mind, here is an example:

```
var options = {
  foo: function(){
    console.log('This is foo');
  },
  toto: function(){
    console.log('This is titi');
  }
};

var example = function(options){
  options.foo();
  options.toto();
}
example(options);
```

---

### Part 3 - Barbaric

```
var three = function() {
    var _foo = function() {};

    three.foo = _foo;
}
```

A good standard when writing code is to keep the code readable. While this may work, it's not good practice. The main issue with writing Javascript is that it can easily become unreadable.. And in this case it feels barbaric (personal opinion).

---

### Conclusion

As you've probably noticed example two is my preferred way (and to many others I know) in declaring Objects for the following reasons:

1. Structured
2. Organized
3. Easy to handle
4. Easy to maintain
5. Flexibility
6. No conflicts

Feel free to point out on anything I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can declare "Objects" via several ways. The most easy way is:

```
var myObject = {}
```

from here on, adding methods or attributes is very easy as well:

```
myObject.myFirstMethod = function(){};
myObject.myFirstAttr = true;
myObject.mySecondAttr = "hello world!";
```

in this case, you would add those functions and attributes to your "myObject" Object. But there is a better and much cleaner way to do such stuff:

```
var myObject = function();
myObject.prototype.method1 = function(){};
myObject.prototype.method2 = functiion(){};
myObject.prototype.attr1 = true;
myObject.prototype.attr2 = "hello world!";
myObject.prototype.setAttr1 = function(value){
    this.attr1 = value;
}
myObject.prototype.setAttr2 = function(value){
    this.attr2 = value;
}
```

if you declared your Object this way, you can use

```
var myObjectInstance = new myObject();
```

this Object now has got every methods and attributes which you had defined in your prototype. more about prototypes:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

edit:

note that "this" in JavaScript means the "element", what called the actual method and NOT the object itself in any case...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this