# Understanding 'this' and 'prototype' in JavaScript ?

Tags: javascript, prototype

what are the difference between,

```
var Human = function(){
this.age = 21;
};
```

and

```
Human.prototype.age = 31;
var ME = new Human();
document.write(ME.age);
```

It showing output 21, why not 31 ?

Comment: Good question, but has been asked before.

Comment: asked and answered 100000s of times :D here is one of my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029318/difference-in-declaring-javascript-objects/31029689#31029689

Comment: This link you pasted here is not answer my question properly.